# Doxygen: strip top level namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, doxygen

When working with library ABC, it natural that all names are included into the same top level `namespace`. Is it possible to remove top level `namespace` from `class` names, but show inclosed `namespaces`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such option inside of Doxygen. Still you can use preprocessor to make it work.

```
#ifndef DOXY_PARSER
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE_STARTS namespace lib_namespace { /##/
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE_ENDS } /##/
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE lib_namespace
#else
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE_STARTS /##/
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE_ENDS /##/
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE
#endif
```

You should include this code into some common header and set predefined `DOXY_PARSER` macro in Doxygen options. This workaround makes using of library namespace less convenient but it is not so crucial.

```
LIB_NAMESPACE_STARTS();
    namespace internal_namespace {
        struct Trololo {};
    }
    LIB_NAMESPACE::internal_namespace::Trololo T;
LIB_NAMESPACE_ENDS();
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a general problem with the previous solution, it is not valid when using Qt. The moc'ing process doesn't use the preprocessor and the namespace is not used (leading to a compile time error).

One possible solution would be to use a `#define QT_NAMESPACE lib_namespace` but it will move the whole Qt to that namespace.

The next solution is more general (I've kept the macros name for convenience):

```
#ifndef DOXY_PARSER
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE lib_namespace
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE_STARTS namespace LIB_NAMESPACE { /##/
    #if (defined MOCED_FILE)
        #define LIB_NAMESPACE_ENDS } using namespace LIB_NAMESPACE; /##/
    #else
        #define LIB_NAMESPACE_ENDS } /##/
    #endif
    #define USING_LIB_NAMESPACE using namespace LIB_NAMESPACE; /##/
#else
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE_STARTS /##/
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE_ENDS /##/
    #define LIB_NAMESPACE
    #define USING_LIB_NAMESPACE /##/
#endif
```

Where `MOCED_FILE` is a define exclusive for mocs. If you are using CMake, you can specify such option using:

```
QT4_WRAP_CPP(mocSources qt_file1.h qt_file2.h)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${mocSources} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-DMOCED_FILE")
```